# How to deal with the following problem of correlated random variables?

Tags: random-variables, correlation

I have the following information:
$\left[ \begin{array}{l}
{X_1}\\
 \vdots \\
{X_K}
\end{array} \right]$ are correlated random variables with (zero mean, unit variance) covariance matrix $\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
1& \ldots &{\rho _{1K}^X}\\
 \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
{\rho _{K1}^X}& \cdots &1
\end{array}} \right)$, and $\left[ \begin{array}{l}
{Y_1}\\
 \vdots \\
{Y_K}
\end{array} \right]$ are correlated random variables with covariance matrix $\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
1& \ldots &{\rho _{1K}^Y}\\
 \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
{\rho _{K1}^Y}& \cdots &1
\end{array}} \right)$. Moreover, $X_i$ and $Y_i$ is also correlated with correlation coefficient $\rho_i$.

Can someone please give me some hints how to generate X and Y?
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the variable $X_i$ is correlated with $Y_j$ with coefficient $\rho_{ij}^{XY}$. Call $Z$ the vector containing $X$ for the first $K$ components and $Y$ for the next $K$.
Then the covariance matrix of $Z$ will be:

$$\mathbf{\Sigma_Z} = \begin{bmatrix}
     \Sigma_X & \Sigma_{XY} \\
     \Sigma_{XY} & \Sigma_Y
  \end{bmatrix}$$

$$\mathbf{\Sigma_X}=\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
1& \ldots &{\rho _{1K}^X}\\
 \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
{\rho _{K1}^X}& \cdots &1
\end{array}} \right)$$

$$\mathbf{\Sigma_Y}=\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
1& \ldots &{\rho _{1K}^Y}\\
 \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
{\rho _{K1}^Y}& \cdots &1
\end{array}} \right)$$

$$\mathbf{\Sigma_{XY}}=\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{\rho _{11}^{XY}}& \ldots &{\rho _{1K}^{XY}}\\
 \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
{\rho _{K1}^{XY}}& \cdots &{\rho _{KK}^{XY}}
\end{array}} \right)$$